# Generating 11x6 matrix of randomly placed 0 and 1

Tags: python, random

I want to generate 11x6 matrix that have randomly placed 0 and 1. I want every row to be symmetric. It is represented by array of 6 arrays of length 11. I used the randint() function from the random module but it generates 6 copies of the same row. Here's my code:

```
import random

def pattern_generator():
    row = [None] * 11
    pattern = [row] * 6
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        for j in range(len(row)):
            x = random.randint(0, 1)
            pattern[i][j] = x
            pattern[i][10 - j] = pattern[i][j]
    return pattern
```

And example of the output:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Can anyone give me any tip what I'm lacking in this function? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace `pattern = [row] * 6` with `pattern = [[None] * 11 for _ in range(6)]` so that you don't get 6 references to the same row (i.e. pattern[0] is the same as pattern[1], ...)

Also, in general it's easier to use numpy for array operations:

```py
import numpy as np
random_array = np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 2, (6, 6))
random_array = np.concatenate((random_array, random_array[:,-1::-1]), axis=1)
print(random_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pattern = [row] * 6` creating an array of 6 elements - each is a reference to the SAME instance of row.

This would probably fix it:

```
def pattern_generator():
    pattern = [None] * 6
    for i in range(len(pattern)):
        row = [None] * 11
        mid = 5;
        row[mid] = random.randint(0,1);
        for j in range(len(row)):
            row[j] = random.randint(0, 1)
            row[10-j] = row[j];
        pattern[i] = row;
    return pattern
```

Unrelated, but worth noting:

```
for j in range(len(row)):
```

Can simply be:

```
let r = len(row)//2 + len(row)%2
for j in range(r):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice()` to randomly select a value from a sequence [1], which in your case would be 0 or 1.

Then you can use list comprehensions to assign the random values to a 2D list of length `rows * columns`.

Conventionally, columns are the length of any given inner list, while rows are the length of the outer list (so to get the output you've provided you would be creating a `6 * 11` matrix).

Here's an implementation:

```
from random import choice

def pattern_generator(rows, columns, values):
    return [[choice(values) for column in range(columns)] for row in range(rows)]

print(pattern_generator(6, 11, [0, 1]))
```

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice